# Tomcat how to set maxage

Tags: security, tomcat, cookies, web, struts2

I am trying to set maxage for a session cookie in tomcat application.
I have made changes in web.xml

```
<session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
         <cookie-config> <max-age>30000</max-age> </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

But google->developertools->Resources->Expires/Max-Age has value SESSION.

Does it mean max-age is not set for cookie ? Or am I doing anything wrong.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Max age is same as expires parameter in cookie and your syntax seems perfect.
The expires parameter was part of the original cookies baked up by Netscape. In HTTP version 1.1, expires was deprecated and replaced with the easier-to-use max-age—instead of having to specify a date, you can just say how long the cookie can live.

> Expires sets an expiry date for when a cookie gets deleted. This is a time from GMT.
>   Max-age sets the time in seconds for when a cookie will be deleted

Comment: Is there a way, I can check if what I have set is working ? Thanks :)

Comment: Yes. You can check in developers tool. There is a cookie tag present in firebug. Or you can download this addon for firefox https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cookies-manager-plus/

Comment: Firefox is also not giving any info on max-age, chrome is atleast giving other info like http only, secure etc. Firefox is not eve giving that. any idea why this might be happening.

Comment: There will be no max age. But the expires time will be there. You have to compare the given max-age value and expires time.

Comment: Firebug has nothing except jsessionid , sorry I am having difficulty with cookie-manager-plus.

Comment: Let me explain a bit more. In your firebug you can see a tab name cookies, inside the tab you will find expires tab(The value will be either session or a particular time).

Comment: Yes it has session, but wont my max-age get stored anywhere to test

Comment: I think you need to work on this more. It should not come as session. Please read this once http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Expires_and_Max-Age